# Flow cannot find schema property on knex

Tags: javascript, flowtype, knex.js

I'm working on a project which uses knex for database connections. I'm also using flow for typings. I'm attempting to connect to the database as follows:

```
const db = knex({
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
        host: containerized() ? 'database' : process.env.DB_URL || 'localhost',
        user: process.env.DB_USER || 'user',
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || 'password',
        database: process.env.DB_DATABASE || 'database',
    },
});
```

where db has the type `Knex$Knex`. I attempt to set up the database with:

```
export function init(): Promise<Knex$Knex<*>> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        PromiseReduce([
            () => db.schema.hasTable('users').then((exists) => {
                if (!exists) {
                    return db.schema.createTable('users', (table) => {
                        ...
                    });
                }
                return null;
            }),
            ...
        ]).then(resolve).catch(reject);
    }).then(() => db);
}
```

This all works when it's run, but flow is erroring, saying that `db.schema` is not a property of `Knex$Knex`; and looking at the type declaration, this is the case. Is there a preferred method to do this, or is it simply a case of the flow declarations being wrong?

Comment: Where did you get flow type definitions for Knex? I didn't think it shipped with any.

Comment: There are some available through flow-typed: https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/tree/master/definitions/npm/knex_v0.14.x

Comment: If the same code works without flow, then I'd assume the type definitions are wrong. Perhaps you could submit a PR to fix it?

Comment: Also, what version of Knex are you using?

Comment: Using knex 0.14.6

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just been missed from the type defs. `schema` has basically _always_ been an attribute there, and has never been in the flow type defs. I can log a bug if you don't want to?

Comment: I have submitted an issue to the flow-typed repo on github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the flow-typed definition for knex v0.14.x does not include typing for the schema.

The error can be quickly fixed locally by adding `schema: Object` to the declaration of the `Knex$Knex<R>` class.

A fix for the issue would require typing the schema for knex properly and adding it to the flow-typed repository.